# ServiceStack In Memory Client Memory Limits

Tags: servicestack

Does your In Memory Client support memory limits as a percentage of total memory available of the application? .NET 4.0 supported memory limits in the web.config. .NET Core doesnt support limits on total memory available. You have to set the size of each cached entry for it to do limits by total units. And getting the size of complex objects in bytes is expensive.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're referring to ServiceStack's default [Memory Cache Client](http://docs.servicestack.net/caching#in-memory-cache), it doesn't, you can only set a `DateTime` **expiresAt** or `TimeSpan` **expiresIn** to specify how long before evicting cached content.